# Filtering queries on django admin site

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model Sessions that contains almost 10,000 objects. Each session has a foreign key relationship to a Subject. The problem is that when loading a page that has a foreign key field to a session, the page takes a long time to load.

To fix this, I like to have an admin on which you select a subject from one ForeignKey field, and have the sessions that have a relationship with that subject appear in a second ForeignKey field.

Is this something that is possible from within the django admin interface? I have checked out django-smart-selects (though I'm unsure if that would actually do what I'd like it to), but when I try to import it I get an error "No module named admin_static", which I believe may be because I'm using an outdated version of Django (v 1.1).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why is the page taking long to load? A foreign key as such should not slow it down. Are you perhaps including something from the `Session` object in `Subject`'s string representation (`.__unicode__()`)? Or displaying something else via that relation on the admin page that takes a long time?

Comment: There is no reference to `Session` in `Subject`'s unicode, however in `Session`'s unicode there is a reference to the `Subject` to which the `Session` has a foreignkey.

Comment: I would suggest to install django-debug-toolbar and check what are the queries for that page load. I believe options could be with extra queries in __unicode__ method, as that mentioned in previous comment.

Comment: Is the `Session` of a `Subject` shown on the admin page for `Subject`s? If so, you've just found the reason for slowness. For every subject you grab a whole lot more subjects via the session. That quickly leads to exponentially increasing page load times.

Comment: It is not - The `Subject` page contains no information about `Session`s. I was unable to get the django-debug-toolbar to work in the past, but I will try again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't just need raw_id_fields?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields

When you visit an admin change form that has a foreign key to Sessions it will build a select dropdown with 10,000 entries. This is probably your slowdown.